# Deleted Local Changes with git push

Tags: git, push

I had local changes. When switching Branches to look at other stuff, I got a Warning. Smart as I am, I created a new Branch, pushed my local changes, but forgot to add and commit....
i guess this is where my mistake happened.

```
$ git push origin reste
-Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
-remote:
-remote: Create a pull request for 'reste' on GitHub by visiting:
....
```

I didn't notice my mistake at the moment and proceed to checkout other branches. After coming back to my branch, everything was gone. I know that my local memory at 5:30 am was still working. Can I get my changes back?

Comment: If you had unsaved work in your working directory and you checked out to another branch, then you may have lost the work.  If you use a modern IDE such as IntelliJ, consider checking the local history of the lost files.

Comment: Already checked the local history. 
Thanks for the answer, gonna get to work again :D....

Comment: `git stash save` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that `git push` won't *delete* anything.<sup>1</sup>  However, if you got this kind of output:

> ```
> Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> ```

it also means that `git push` didn't really *push* anything either.  If you did *something else* that deleted something, that could be the source of the problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is an exception if you use `git push` to push from your repository to your repository on your local computer *and* add `--force`, but you didn't do that.  It's somewhat unusual, to say the least, to use `git push` to push from your computer to itself.  (You do this with `git push .`, which by itself is quite pointless.  Some people like the special effect you can get this way, though, when using a fuller *refspec* with `git push`, as in `git push . br1:br2` for instance.  You can get yourself in trouble—deleting things—by doing `git push --force . br1:br2`.  But, again, you didn't do that, so your `git push` did not delete anything.)

Comment: Thanks for all this information. I guess I should have read the Lines after pushing my version. Nevertheless I stashed my savings afterwards, cause I though they were saved in a new branch. Mistakes were made, but I learned a lot about git while trying to solve my issue.